# Can't Insert an array in table column, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to insert an array in a table column with other non array inputs, But each time it's inserting a string "Array" ,

My codes are :

```
$post_data['product_category'] = "Goods";
    $post_data['product_profile'] = "physical-goods";

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($request->package_type_id); $i++) {
        $answers[] = [
            $post_data['package_type_id'] =$request->package_type_id,
        ];
    }

   
    $update_product = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('transaction_id', $post_data['tran_id'])
        ->updateOrInsert([
            'name' => $post_data['cus_name'],
            'email' => $post_data['cus_email'],
            'phone' => $post_data['cus_phone'],
            'amount' => $post_data['total_amount'],
            'status' => 'Pending',
            'address' => $post_data['cus_add1'],
            'transaction_id' => $post_data['tran_id'],
            'currency' => $post_data['currency'],
            'package_type_id' =>  implode($answers,',')
        ]);
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Which column are you talking about?

Comment: the last one ""package_type_id

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? What does `$answers` contain? Please don't guess, but properly debug that, either through vardump or through XDebug

Comment: I am getting this : [when dd($answers)]

array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "1"
      1 => "2"
    ]
  ]
]

Comment: That looks like a nested array - is that what it should contain?

Comment: It should contain only the contents of the second array

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve that? I would assume that the loop building `$answers` does not work as expected, so you need to fix that

Comment: I just want to insert the contents (from the second array : 1,2) in a column

Comment: how do I fix it

Comment: Then please do that. What have you tried to resolve that problem? Where are you stuck? Is this in any way related to `$post_data['package_type_id']` which you override in each iteration of that loop?

Comment: Either implode the array to insert as a string or use a JSON column and json_encode your array to insert it.

Comment: `$post_data['package_type_id'] =$request->package_type_id` is invalid inside an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gone a long way, I think you just want to make a string from the `$request->package_type_id` which I assume is an array.

```php
$post_data['product_category'] = "Goods";
$post_data['product_profile'] = "physical-goods";

$post_data['package_type_id'] = implode(',', $request->package_type_id);

$update_product = DB::table('orders')
    ->where('transaction_id', $post_data['tran_id'])
    ->updateOrInsert([
        // ...
        'package_type_id' =>  $post_data['package_type_id']
    ]);
```

Also note that the syntax for implode is `implode(glue, array)` not the other way around.